# Navigation Active/Hover/Inactive state through JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hover

The code below is what I have but unfortunately it's not doing anything. Previously I had a section working for swapping images but it was much simpler code... If there is a easier way to do it I'm all ears.

To recap what I am trying to accomplish is:

Land on home page > Nothing selected in nav
Hover over - image swaps to selected state
On click image is swapped to selected state.

Thanks for any help!

The other problem I am having is that the files I was given by the artist have the text in the image. I have two different images one in the selected state with the text and one in the inactive state with the text. So I can't put the text above it.

**Jquery**

```
var menu = {
init: function () {

    $('.nav-image').hover(function () {
        if (!$(this).attr('id') != menu._selectedId + '-nav' && $(this).attr('src').indexOf("_on.png") == -1) {
            var src = $(this).attr('src').replace("_off.png", "_on.png");
            $(this).attr('src', src);
        }
    },

        function () {

            if ((page == "index" && $(this).attr('id') != "index-nav") || (page == "about" && $(this).attr('id') != "about-nav") || (page == "portfolio" && $(this).attr('id') != "portfolio-nav") || (page == "blog" && $(this).attr('id') != "blog-nav") || (page == "contact" && $(this).attr('id') != "contact-nav") || page == "index") {
                if (!$(this).attr('id') != menu._selectedId + '-nav' && $(this).attr('src').indexOf("_on.png") >= 0) {
                    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace("_on.png", "_off.png");
                    $(this).attr('src', src);
                }
            }
        });

}}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div style="float: left; hieght: 45px; width: 193px;"><img src="images/nav/left_end.png" class="nav-image"></div>
    <div style="float: left; height: 45px; width: 73px;"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/nav/home_off.png" class="nav-image" id="index-nav"></a></div>
    <div style="float: left; height: 45px; width: 80px;"><a href="about.php"><img src="images/nav/about_off.png" class="nav-image" id="about-nav"></a></div>
    <div style="float: left; height: 45px; width: 112px;"><a href="portfolio.php"><img src="images/nav/portfolio_off.png" class="nav-image" id="portfolio-nav"></a></div>
    <div style="float: left; height: 45px; width: 69px;"><a href="http://info.arkmediainc.com/blog"><img src="images/nav/blog_off.png" class="nav-image" id="blog-nav"></a></div>
    <div style="float: left; height: 45px; width: 98px;"><a href="http://info.arkmediainc.com/contact-us"><img src="images/nav/contact_off.png" class="nav-image" id="contact-nav"></a></div>
    <div style="float: left; height: 45px; width: 35px;"><img src="images/nav/right_end.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have CSS do it for you.

Each div could be a background image of any menu item, which could also allow you to have text over it.

Then use code similar to [this sample](http://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/).

So you could have cleaner code, for each link :

```
<div class="nav home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>

<script>
jQuery('.nav').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).css("background-image",jQuery(this).css("background-image").replace("on","clicked");
});
<script>

<style>
.nav {
    float: left; 
    height: 45px; 
    width: 73px;;
}

.home {
    background-image: url("images/nav/home_off.png");
    }

.home:hover {
    background-image: url("images/nav/home_on.png");
    }

</style>
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that the files I was given by the artist have the text in the image. I have two different images one in the selected state with the text and one in the inactive state with the text. So I can't put the text above it.

Comment: just place "&nbsp;" or <br/> instead of text, the text is not needed

Comment: The real funny bit is, I needed to do exactly the same today, now I have the answer already! Stack Overflow is great!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you put the images in css as background-images to 2 classes, and then just toggle the classes on the elements.